# Cannot configure Data Source in IntelliJ IDEA using Oracle Wallet

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea, datagrip, oracle-wallet

I have a working Oracle Wallet. I'm trying to configure a Data Source in IntelliJ IDEA (and/or DataGrip) that uses a `TNS` connection type. Under the `General` tab, I filled up the `TNSADMIN` field with the location of the Oracle Wallet (that contains only the files: `cwallet.sso`, `ewallet.p12`, `sqlnet.ora`, and `tnsnames.ora`...nothing else), and `TNS name` with the actual data source name.

> There is an environment variable `WALLET_HOME` that points to the exact location also.

Additionally I have modified (under the `Advanced` tab) the keys `oracle.net.tns_admin` and `oracle.net.wallet_location` with the values: `${WALLET_HOME}` and `(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=${WALLET_HOME})))` respectively.

> That's pretty much what I have to do to connect to the Oracle database within the application(s).

So it looks that it might work, but I'm getting then this error message: `[99999][17167] PKI classes not found. To use 'connect /' functionality, oraclepki.jar must be in the classpath: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet.`

But I cannot find in this life a place to augment the Java classpath in that screen. I cannot provide a `-classpath` option as part of the `VM options` (under `Advanced` tab) because it will overwrite it.

Can someone using this setup shed some light here?

Comment: what is your Oracle version? file can be added directly to drivers file section in driver properties.

Comment: You were right! On the `Data Sources and Drivers` window there is a `Drivers` section where you can add more files and/or sub-directories. For me what worked was adding the `oraclepki.jar` file (located at `../oracle12c2_client_64/product/12.2.0/client_1/jlib/oraclepki.jar`). If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a file to driver please follow this instruction:

1. Navigate to File | Data Sources or press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S.
2. In the Data Sources and Drivers dialog, click the driver entry to which you want to add a file.
3. In the Driver files pane, click the (+) icon (Add) and select Custom JARs.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip 2021.1 provides Oracle 21.1 JDBC driver with all required jar files.

Also, read DataGrip help article [Connect to Oracle Cloud by using wallets](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connect-to-oracle-cloud-by-using-wallets.html)﻿

Comment: While they both are quite similar, I was using indeed IntelliJ IDEA. Probably the DataGrip solution applies to it.

Comment: They are similar. DataGrip goes as a plugin to IntelliJ IDEA.